# How format URL android

Tags: java, android, url

I get from **`URL`** the following **url** not formatted:

```
"http:\\/\\/www.video.mediaset.it\\/bin\\/635.$plit\\/640x360_C_2_video_772135_videoThumbnail.jpg\\\"
```

but i need it formatted as

```
http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/635.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_772135_videoThumbnail.jpg
```

How can i resolve my issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you test this code?

```
String text = "http:\\/\\/www.video.mediaset.it\\/bin\\/635.$plit\\/640x360_C_2_video_772135_videoThumbnail.jpg";
try {
    String afterDecode = URLDecoder.decode(text, "UTF-8");
    Log.e("text", afterDecode);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the `URI`

`(Uri.parse(string))` API of `Android`.
For more information refer below link:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [urllib](https://github.com/EricEdens/urllib). Parsing into the `org.urllib.Url` object will fix the slash directions, and remove empty path segments.

```
String raw = "http:\\/\\/www.video.mediaset.it\\/bin\\/635.$plit\\/640x360_C_2_video_772135_videoThumbnail.jpg";
String expected = "http://www.video.mediaset.it/bin/635.$plit/640x360_C_2_video_772135_videoThumbnail.jpg";
assertEquals(expected, Url.parse(raw).toString());
```